Whitespace warnings with fastparse
I've written several parsers with fastparse and it has been very successful but latterly I'm getting build warnings from SBT in visual studio code.
I want to ignore whitespace so I have the imports
import fastparse._
import fastparse.MultiLineWhitespace._

But for all of the parsers I get a set of warnings like this:
comparing values of types fastparse.MultiLineWhitespace.whitespace.type and fastparse.NoWhitespace.noWhitespaceImplicit.type using `ne` will always yield true
The warning comes from definitions like this in my parsers:
def identifier[$: P]                = P( CharIn("a-zA-Z_") ~~/ CharIn("a-zA-Z_0-9").rep(0)).!.map(x => Identifier(x))

VsCode is highlighting the rep(0) with this warning.
It seems to have only just started happening and doesn't stop the parser working but having lots of warnings is a bit irritating.
Can anyone suggest why I'm getting this warning?
David

Fastparse's P is a macro. The macro get expanded to code that uses ne in a way that causes the compiler to warn.
As documented at the scala compiled options you can prevent the warnings by using the compiler option -Ywarn-macros:none.

I tried scalacOptions ++= Seq(          // use ++= to add to existing options   "-encoding", "utf8",          // if an option takes an arg, supply it on the same line   "-Ywarn-macros:none", )     but it makes no difference, so I tried the equivalent scalacOptions ++= Seq(          // use ++= to add to existing options   "-encoding", "utf8",          // if an option takes an arg, supply it on the same line   "-Wmacros:none",              )    and this stops the warnings but bizarrely running tests doesn't work (they now do nothing).

Note this is known issue with fastparse, see https://github.com/com-lihaoyi/fastparse/issues/279 . Apparently an upgrade to 2.13 will fix the issue but I can't do that because I need to build for Databricks which is stuck on 2.12.
